# Basic question about the definition of a variety (in universal algebra)

Tags: universal-algebra

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_HSP_theorem),

> A variety is a class of algebraic structures of the same signature
>   that is closed under the taking of homomorphic images, subalgebras and
>   (direct) products.

Isn't the stipulation about subalgebras redundant? I think that every subalgebra can be viewed as the image of an injective homomorphism.

Comment: They might mean "substructure" rather than "subalgebra".

Comment: @ZhenLin, aren't they the same?

Comment: No. A substructure of a field (considered as a structure in the language of rings) is not necessarily a field.

Comment: @ZhenLin, okay. So is it not the case that, for a general mathematical structure $X$, every substructure of $X$ can be expressed as the image of a homomorphism $f : Y \rightarrow X$.

Comment: @ZhenLin: No, they mean a subalgebra. The class of all fields is not a variety of algebras.

Comment: That's the point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the misunderstanding may be with the term homomorphic image. To say a class $\mathcal{K}$ of algebras is closed under homomorphic images means that if $\mathbf{A}\in\mathcal{K}$ and $h:\mathbf{A}\to\mathbf{B}$ is a homomorphism, then the image $h(\mathbf{A})$ is in $\mathcal{K}$.

If you have an algebra $\mathbf{Y}$ and an injective homomorphism $f:\mathbf{Y}\to\mathbf{X}$, then closure under homomorphic image would not give you anything new since you are assuming you already have $\mathbf{Y}$. However, if $\mathbf{X}$ has a subalgebra $\mathbf{Z}$ that you do not already have in your class, then it is possible that you cannot realize it as a homomorphic image.

For example, if we consider the variety generated by the ring $\mathbb{Q}$. Then the only homomorphic images of $\mathbb{Q}$ are itself and the trivial ring $\{0\}$ (since fields are simple commutative rings). However, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.